# How to catkin_make_isolated a non-catkin package when CMakeLists.txt not in pkg root

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cmake, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We'd like to make our projects self-contained, so we are adding all possible (external) packages to our GIT repo as submodule, and build our project with `catkin_make_isolated`. This works with Ceres, Google Cartographer, etc., but does not seem to be working with some other module.

I added it as submodule, but the problem (apart from the missing `package.xml`, which I created) is that the `CMakeLists.txt` file is in a `cmake/` directory, not in the package root. It looks like `catkin_make_isolated` fails to find the `cmake/CMakeLists.txt` file.

Moving or symlinking does not work, as the file uses other files in the `cmake/` directory.

Is there a way to force catkin to look for `CMakeLists.txt` in `cmake/`?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298388/how-to-catkin_make_isolated-a-non-catkin-package-when-cmakelists.txt-not-in-pkg-root/) by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While knowing more specifics about which package you're looking at would help give a more confident answer, I think the following may help:

1. Add a new top-level CMakeLists.txt file in the location catkin is expecting
2. Fill it with the basics (`cmake_mininum_required(..)`, `project(...)`, etc.)
3. Use `add_subdirectory(cmake)` to tell catkin to look in the 'cmake' directory for another CMakeLists.txt file

---

Originally posted by [mbarulic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36629/mbarulic/) with karma: 51 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hi! Thank you, this solved the problem! I tried add_subdirectory before, but I did something wrong. Now everything is fine. (The package was google protocol buffer, protobuf3.)